# Adding boolen to LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, boolean

I am supposed to create list of `Cannon` objects (restricted to use `for-loop`) and load every `Cannon` that is not loaded.

My problem lies here:

```java
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
    Random randomizer = new Random();
    Cannon cannon = new Cannon (randomizer.nextBoolean());
    List <Cannon> Cannons = new LinkedList <Cannon>();
    for (int i=0; i <randomizer.nextInt(99)+1; i++){
    cannon = randomizer.nextBoolean();
    Cannons.add(cannon);
}
```

the program results with error `incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to Cannon, line 33`

If you want to see the whole Code here is the link:
https://kodilla.com/pl/project-java/175236

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating one instance of type `Cannon` and then trying to re-assign it no another type (in this case a boolean).

Java is statically typed. You cannot re-assign one type to another type just like that.

If you need to populate a list with variables, then just do the following

```java
// Remove this method here
Cannon cannon = new Cannon (randomizer.nextBoolean());

// and place it in the for-loop
for (int i = 0; i < randomizer.nextInt(99) + 1; i++) {
    Cannon cannon = new Cannon(randomizer.nextBoolean());
    Cannons.add(cannon);
}
```

Comment: Ofc there is no need to create a new reference each time inside a loop ;)

Comment: Ah yes of course. Just wanted to make a point that it's one way to populate a list of type A.